# Remove duplicates by priority

Tags: c#, list, linq, duplicates

I have a List of a class containing an id and a priority, like this:

[image: List of member ids]

This list can contain many entries and some of them can be duplicates.

If an id already exists in the list I need to select the one with the highest priority. in this example the first two entries have the same Id's but different priorities. So the one with the lower priority has to be excluded from the list.

Does anybody have an advice for me? Would be highly appreciated.

Comment: GroupBy Id, OrderBy Priority, Take One

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and then order each group by priority and take the first:

```
var highPrioUniqueItemList = listmembers
    .GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.priority).First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you very much...could have come up with it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible approaches:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Guid guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item
            {
                ID = guid1,
                Priority = 1
            },
            new Item
            {
                ID = guid1,
                Priority = 2
            },
            new Item
            {
                ID = guid1,
                Priority = 3
            },
            new Item
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Priority = 1
            },
            new Item
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Priority = 2
            },
            new Item
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Priority = 3
            },
        };

        //IF YOU CAN CHANGE THE LIST
        items = items.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Priority).First()).ToList();

        //IF YOU CAN CHANGE ONLY LIST ITEMS
        items.RemoveAll(z => items.GroupBy(x => x.ID).SelectMany(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Priority).Skip(1).ToList()).ToList().Contains(z));
    }
}
public class Item
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```